# Sync multiple tables with Microsoft Azure MobileService

Tags: ios, azure, synchronization, azure-mobile-services

I am currently trying the Azure mobile services on iOS and the quickstart work very well but I have questions about the good strategy for syncing data with relationship. Do I need to instantiate multiple SyncTable et and sync one after another? Did I miss something?

The current example show how to sync only one table but no releationship or multiple tables at the same time.

I want to know if there a way to sync multiple tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using native iOS, you can follow this [Mobile Services sample for multiple tables](https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-dynamics-connector/blob/master/MobileServicesCrm/client/AzureActivityLogger.iOS/Azure%20Activity%20Logger/AzureConnector/AzureConnector.m#L233). Simply sync each one in sequence using continuation blocks.

The reason that all of the pull calls are done independently is that you can control how often to pull individual tables.

There's no built-in support for relationships, but you can use Mobile Services with Automapper [(blog post here)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/27/how-to-expand-linked-entities-from-mobileservices-client-and-mobileservices-service.aspx) to flatten relationships.